# How to disable HTML tags in a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page to show a log file, sometimes the log file contains some html tags and they make my page run slower since the tags are converted to contents like pictures etc., I want to disable that, so my goal is to show those tags as texts only, they should never be converted to contents.

This is the [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)that I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "ssh.log",
        success: function(result) {
          $("#ssh").html(result);
        }
      });
      var textarea = document.getElementById("ssh");
      textarea.scrollTop = textarea.scrollHeight;
    }, 1000);
  });
</script>
```

And my `div` looks like this:

```
<div id="ssh"></div>
```

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
$("#ssh").html(result);
```

to

```
$("#ssh").text(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `.text()` to render content as a text:

```
$("#ssh").text(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answers have said, use `.text()` to render it as just plaintext. If for some reason you need to keep it as `.html()`, you can use simple string replacement to escape the tags.

```
result = result.replace('<','&lt;');
$('#ssh').html(result);
```